# Devise - Allow Admin to Add Registration Accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I was wondering if we can allow Admins to add Accounts for the Member Models? with out them having to confirm it if the Admin adds it?

I have two Devise Models

> Admins
>
> Members

To Launch the application i want to restrict Registration and Admins will create the Logins for Members from the Admin Scope. When he adds the Member i dont want them to confirm their account but just send a welcome Email may be with the login details.

Comment: What about the new members password? The admin will put it manually?

Comment: @Vucko yes sir Admin will set it

Comment: So just create a form for the `Member` model. The form needs to have `email` and `password` field, and in the controller save it with with also `password_confirmation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want them to confirm their account but just send a welcome Email may be with the login details

One way you could do this is by simply writing a new user form, saving the user and manually sending an email. If you are using [Devise confirmable](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable), then you must call [`confirm!`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable#confirm%21-instance_method) on the built object, in order for them to log in.

However, sending a password in plain text is generally speaking a dodgy thing to do. Surely you'd then want to force each user to change their password anyway, for security reasons? As such, I'd recommend going for the more standard approach of [Devise invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) - which will send an invitation token to the user, and ask them to set their initial password. You achieve this by calling [`invite!`](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#send-an-invitation) on the built user object.

Here are two RailsCast videos about Devise, which you may find helpful for further reference and examples:

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just create the object and call `confirm` on it :)

However, as members will need a password to access their account, it could be nice to email them a link to enter this password, so this link could also confirm the account for you.

IMHO, It's a bad practice to send any password by email, a lot of email servers don't implement any secured protocol, better let your users chose it, with a one-time link